# Intellij Plugin - How to color project view files background?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

[image]

As seen in the picture. Color Notification is colored. This is done by creating a scope and adding that file in that scope.

However I want to mark files according to my need. For example I will click that color notification and mark that file green or yellow.

**I only need to know how I can reach this project view and alter background color programmatically.**

I know there arent so many intellij plugin creators but still I will try my luck.

From my investigation there are FileColorManager, ProjectView, UIManager etc but I couldnt find which one is responsible for  these color handling changes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess. Have you tried to implement the `com.intellij.ide.projectView.ProjectViewNodeDecorator` extension point? It seems like this lets you decorate the nodes in the project view.

As we found out, setting the background-color is not easily possible. But you can add a string (like a checkmark) at the end of each node that you want to highlight. Here is an example:

```
public class ProvectViewColorer implements ProjectViewNodeDecorator {

  @Override
  public void decorate(ProjectViewNode node, PresentationData data) {
    final VirtualFile virtualFile = node.getVirtualFile();
    if (virtualFile != null && virtualFile.getFileType().equals(MathematicaFileType.INSTANCE)) {
      data.setLocationString("✓");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void decorate(PackageDependenciesNode node, ColoredTreeCellRenderer cellRenderer) {

  }
}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `editorTabColorProvider` extension point in `plugin.xml`:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <editorTabColorProvider implementation="com.example. MyEditorTabColorProvider" />
</extensions>
```

And override `getProjectViewColor` method:

```
class MyEditorTabColorProvider : EditorTabColorProvider {
    override fun getProjectViewColor(project: Project, file: VirtualFile): Color? {
        return getColor(project, file)
    }

    override fun getEditorTabColor(project: Project, file: VirtualFile): Color? {
        return getColor(project, file)
    }

    private fun getColor(project: Project, file: VirtualFile): JBColor? {
        return if (isMarked(file)) {
            JBColor.GREEN
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```